# Adding decimal hours using DATEADD in Oracle SQL

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have the following piece of query which works fine for adding hours to a time value:

```
to_char(date_add('h', trunc(o.tt_real)::integer, d.pickup_date::timestamp),'HH24:MI') injection_time
```

In the above tt_real is an integer. Now lets assume I have a tt with decimal hours like this 2.98, 3.55 etc. Can someone suggest an updated version of the above query to incorporate decimal hours ?
An example of the output expected 
10:30 + 2.25 = 12:45

Comment: DATEADD (or DATE_ADD) don't exist in Oracle, as far as I can tell. Also, syntax you use (those double colons, `::`) look suspicious, I've never seen that either. Are you sure it is Oracle we're talking about?

Comment: Looks like a mix of SQL Server and PostgreSQL -:).

Comment: Actually the database is redshift hence I have corrected the tag.

Answer (score 0):

rather add minutes instead of hours: `(o.tt_real*60)::integer`

Comment: (obviously switching to minute literal in the first argument of date_add)